# Using bindings to control column order in a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, mvvm, wpftoolkit

**Problem**

I have a WPF Toolkit `DataGrid`, and I'd like to be able to switch among several preset column orders. This is an MVVM project, so the column orders are stored in a `ViewModel`. The problem is, I can't get bindings to work for the `DisplayIndex` property. No matter what I try, including the sweet method in [this Josh Smith tutorial](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/josh_smith/archive/2008/06/26/data-binding-the-isvisible-property-of-contextualtabgroup.aspx), I get:

> The DisplayIndex for the DataGridColumn with Header 'ID' is out of range.  DisplayIndex must be greater than or equal to 0 and less than Columns.Count. Parameter name: displayIndex. Actual value was -1.

**Is there any workaround for this?**

I'm including my test code below. Please let me know if you see any problems with it.

---

**ViewModel code**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
    public int IdDisplayIndex { get; set; }
    public int NameDisplayIndex { get; set; }
    public int DescriptionDisplayIndex { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        IdDisplayIndex = 1;
        NameDisplayIndex = 2;
        DescriptionDisplayIndex = 0;
        Plans = new List<Plan>
        {
            new Plan { Id = 1, Name = "Primary", Description = "Likely to work." },
            new Plan { Id = 2, Name = "Plan B", Description = "Backup plan." },
            new Plan { Id = 3, Name = "Plan C", Description = "Last resort." }
        };
    }
}
```

---

**Plan Class**

```
public class Plan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Window code** - this uses [Josh Smith's DataContextSpy](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/josh_smith/archive/2008/06/26/data-binding-the-isvisible-property-of-contextualtabgroup.aspx)

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:mwc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    Title="Main Window" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <mwc:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Plans}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <mwc:DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:DataContextSpy x:Key="spy" />
            </mwc:DataGrid.Resources>
            <mwc:DataGrid.Columns>
                <mwc:DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="ID" 
                    Binding="{Binding Id}"
                    DisplayIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource spy}, Path=DataContext.IdDisplayIndex}" />
                <mwc:DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Name"
                    Binding="{Binding Name}"
                    DisplayIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource spy}, Path=DataContext.NameDisplayIndex}" />
                <mwc:DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Description"
                    Binding="{Binding Description}"
                    DisplayIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource spy}, Path=DataContext.DescriptionDisplayIndex}" />
            </mwc:DataGrid.Columns>
        </mwc:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**Note:** If I just use plain numbers for `DisplayIndex`, everything works fine, so the problem is definitely with the bindings.

---

**Update 5/1/2010**

I was just doing a little maintenance on my project, and I noticed that when I ran it, the problem I discuss in this post had returned. I knew that it worked last time I ran it, so I eventually narrowed the problem down to the fact that I had installed a newer version of the WPF Toolkit (Feb '10). When I reverted to the June '09 version, everything worked fine again. So, I'm now doing something I should have done in the first place: I'm including the WPFToolkit.dll that works in my solution folder and checking it into version control. It's unfortunate, though, that the newer toolkit has a breaking change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(My previous answer was way off track - so I deleted it - I'll try to answer again after reproducing the error on my machine)

The problem you encounter stems from the fact that when the bindings are evaluated for the first time, the `DataContext` property is still set to `null`. This, for some strange reason, yet unknown to me, causes the binding to evaluate at `-1`. However if you make sure to set the `DataContext` **before** the bindings are evaluated you'll be ok. Unfortunately this might only be possible in code-behind - hence during run-time, and not in design time. So in design time I still don't know how to circumvent the error.

To do that, set the `DataContext` property of the window before the call to `InitializeComponent` thus:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well this is interesting. If I run my test app, your fix works perfectly. In my real app, the `DataGrid` in question is actually in a `UserControl`, and for some reason, if I apply the `DataContextSpy` (which I didn't try until just now since it had failed for my test app), it works even if I don't postpone the call to `InitializeComponent()`. I think this must be because I'm just setting the `Content` on a `ContentControl` rather than doing `window.Show()`. In any case, thanks for taking the time to solve this for me (+1 and √).

Answer (score 14):

Set `FallbackValue=<idx>` in your DisplayIndex binding, where `<idx>` is your column's index.  For example:

```
DisplayIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource spy}, Path=DataContext.IdDisplayIndex, FallbackValue=0}" />
```

Comment: Works perfectly - and graceful too.

Comment: This is the way to go, hands down.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this as an answer since I can't comment yet. The reason why the value of the DisplayIndex is set to -1 is :

> The DisplayIndex property has a default value of -1 before it is added
>   to the DataGrid.Columns collection. This value is updated when the
>   column is added to the DataGrid.
>
> The DataGrid requires that the DisplayIndex property of each column
>   must be a unique integer from 0 to the Count of Columns -1. Therefore,
>   when the DisplayIndex of one column changes, the change typically
>   causes the DisplayIndex of other columns to also change.
>
> The restrictions on the DisplayIndex value are enforced by a
>   ValidateValueCallback mechanism. If you attempt to set a value that is
>   not valid, a run-time exception is thrown.
>
> When the value of the DisplayIndex property is changed, the
>   DataGrid.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged event is raised.

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.displayindex(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.displayindex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So I suppose that it is possible to check this value when it is changed using the aforementioned event.

The solution mentioned by Aviad didn't work for me. I have my Datagrid in a UserControl, same as the OP, and changing the order of the `ViewModel` constructor, the `DataContext` declaration, and the `InitializeComponent()` method didn't help.

Pakman's `FallbackValue` method worked very well, on the other hand.